# No 'Use system certificates' options on Samsung S9

Tags: wi-fi, samsung

I'm trying to connect to a wifi network using PEAP, but I cannot find the use system certificate option, shall I enable that in some way?

Comment: Have you installed the required certificate? May be the option is hidden if no certificate is available (avoid confusion for regular users).

Comment: It says system certificate so I doubt I need to install it. I had the option on my s7 and i did not install anything (at least, not intentionally).

Comment: On my Android device when I see the list of Wifi APs in settings the option menu contains an "Install certificate" entry. However my device is not a Samsung device.

Comment: I have this too. On a galaxy s8

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197261/no-use-system-certificates-when-trying-to-connect-to-wifi/201576#201576

Comment: Did you find a solution? My Note 9 has no option Use system certificates BUT my LG G6 has ( setting to the same company wifi ). So frustrated!

Comment: No I didn't, sorry :(