# No "Use system certificates" when trying to connect to WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, certificates

I am having a problem connecting to my university Eduroam WiFi.

If I understand correctly, in `CA certificate` I am supposed to select `CA certificate` if it is there or `Use system certificate` and input my university domain.

But, I only have: `Select certificate` or `Don't validate`. And if I click `Select certificate`, nothing is changing, there is not a `Domain` field appearing like I think it should (and where I could the domain name) (see screenshot).

[image]

Can you help?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162927/how-to-connect-to-peap-mschapv2-wi-fi-using-system-certificates-in-android-7-1-n

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem at my university (not Eduroam) by installing a CA certificate in Android (8). It then becomes a choice in the **CA Certificate** menu and you can sign in.

Hopefully, you can find out from the IT people where is the CA Certificate to download to your Android.

I think choosing "Don't validate" is unwise, and that's actually what many university IT web sites advise (Google finds the instructions easily).

Edit: for Eduroam, there's an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.ac.swansea.eduroamcat&hl=en) that reportedly solves the problem for Android 8.

Comment: The CA certificate you installed came from the university, right?  How did you get it?

Comment: @endolith That's a funny question. I actually obtained it by seeing how my Windows 10 PC connected to the WiFi (I exported the same certificate it downloads somehow). But you're right - the IT people from the university should provide it to you. Some universities feel that is a security risk to provide it (?). Maybe others have no clue it even exists because they paid consultants to set up their Wifi and it "just works." At my university, the attitude with Android requiring pre-installed certificates is "this is a problem with your phone, not our servers."

Comment: I actually need the certificate for my ISP's Wi-Fi nodes, but they *also* have no clue it even exists...  Quote from their tech support: "you need to contact the manufacture of the phone so they can assist you on how to get access to this certificates." 

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Do you have a link how to do that export frim windows?

Comment: @lucidbrot sadly I don't. I managed to do it on a new windows 10 system that had not connected to the school's wifi and then I exported the certificate.https://www.top-password.com/blog/view-installed-certificates-in-windows-10-8-7/ I suppose you could also create a new user on the Windows system and view the added certificate that way?

Comment: @lucidbrot if that link works for you, let me know and I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I hope I will find time to try it out before the semester kicks in. But yes, if it works I will let you know

Answer (score 1):

For Eduroam specifically, there seems to be a CA Certificate installer available for many operating systems to be found at [cat.eduroam.org](https://cat.eduroam.org/).

It is specific to your Institution and features Linux, Windows, Mac OS, Android, ChromeOS and iOS.